# talkback not focusing by default on any view on start of inner fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, autofocus, talkback, accessibility

I am using accessibility talkback functionality and I am facing one problem I have one bottom navigation in the parent activity and from the setting tab I am opening another fragment(inner fragment) using `.add` but the inner fragment view not getting focus by default

I also tried with `. replace` but it's not focusing by default on fragment creation.

open fragment code

```
val details = DetailsFragment.newInstance();
getSupportFragmentManager().setupForAccessibility()
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit()
```

and I used this extension function to not get focus on the previous fragment from this [source](https://www.polidea.com/blog/accessibility-mistakes-to-avoid-when-implementing-it-in-an-android-app/)

```
fun FragmentManager.setupForAccessibility() {
    addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        val lastFragmentWithView = fragments.lastOrNull { it.view != null }
        for (fragment in fragments) {
            if (fragment == lastFragmentWithView) {
                fragment.view?.importantForAccessibility =
                        View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES
            } else {
                fragment.view?.importantForAccessibility =
                        View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in normal I show that at the start of the first fragment it's focusing top first `Textview` and speaking automatic but in the inner fragment it's not focusing by default so what should I do to get focus by default on the first view by default

I already try

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and request focus but it's not working

Please suggest me any help would be highly appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the best luck using

```
view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

on the view you want to focus, or maybe

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
}, someDelayMillis)
```

to let the system do whatever it does, and then jump in after a moment and force a focus change.

But this might be considered bad accessibility, if it's interfering with the usual navigation, and that might be why it's so hard to get focus working consistently! It might be better to just announce the new fragment (with something like `view.announceForAccessibility("new fragment")`) and let the user start navigating from the top. It depends on your app, it's your call

Also you probably want to use `replace` for your fragment instead of `add`, if you add a fragment on top of an old one, TalkBack can get stuck looking at the "invisible" views on the old fragment

Comment: I tried both .add and . replace but inner fragment not getting focus by default

Comment: The ``add`` problem is more if you do swipe navigation and it's focusing on views you can't actually see anymore, like it's stuck on the old fragment. ``replace`` just avoids that, it won't force a default focus. Try the ``AccessibilityEvent`` stuff, that's what works for me - but only sometimes, accessibility is really hard to work with :(

Comment: Thank you, I just implemented this and it's working like a charm

Comment: yes you are right i am getting old fragment view on navigation

Answer (score 0):

this is my improved code that extends from @cactustictacs

```
//target to specific a view
binding.getRoot().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            binding.textView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
        }
}, 300);
```

full: https://github.com/dotrinh-PM/AndroidTalkback